# Two way data binding to a Form control

Tags: typescript, angular

I am trying to bind an input to a form control. Here is the input:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="someProperty" ngControl="someProperty">
```

And in the component

```
someProperty: Control;

someForm:ControlGroup;

...

constructor(private _form_builder: FormBuilder){

    this.someProperty = new Control('', Validators.required);

    this.someForm = this._form_builder.group({

        someProperty:this.someProperty

    });

}
```

So, is it allowed to bind input to a Form Control? Evidently i cannot do this as my input box is filled with `[object Object]` when i run. So what is the proper way to do this? I can create seperate property and do the two way binding that way but shouldn't the controls be able to handle bindings?

Comment: FYI...`ngCtrl` is mainly concerned current status of `ctrl` where ngModel is concerned with binding values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`someProperty` needs to be the value of the `<input>`. This would be a string. `ngControl` should refer the control

```ts
<input [(ngModel)]="somePropertyValue" ngControl="someProperty">
```

```ts
somePropertyValue: string;

someProperty: Control;

someForm:ControlGroup;

...

constructor(private _form_builder: FormBuilder){

    this.someProperty = new Control('', Validators.required);

    this.someForm = this._form_builder.group({

        someProperty:this.someProperty

    });

}
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

Comment: I understand that but is there no way we can use the control for both? As i remember the control has a value too.

Comment: `Control` has a `value` but is not supposed to be bound to. What's the purpose anyway? I haven't tried but if you omit the `[(ngModel)]="somePropertyValue"` you might get what you want anyway.

Comment: I was just worried about the right approach. But it seems like i can use controls and properties for same

Comment: `Control` is about the behavior of the `<input>`, the model is just the value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bind a form control to an input, you need to use the `ngFormControl` directive:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="somePropertyValue"
       [ngFormControl]="someProperty">
```

or

```
<input [(ngModel)]="somePropertyValue" 
       [ngFormControl]="someForm.controls.someProperty">
```

The `ngControl` directive is only to define inline controls.

See this article for more details:

- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/02/11/implementing-angular2-forms-beyond-basics-part-1/